# MPAndroidChart how to set y-axis min and max value or set default zoom?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I use [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to display the stock chart, but the Y line value is so close,the chart is like this [image]

I can use finger zoom like this way [image]

Which is I want the default looks like

Is there any way to set Y line max and min value or set default zoom.

I tried the lib function , but it does not work

Answer (score 42):

Take a look at the [**documentation of the YAxis**](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/yaxis/). There are various methods that allow you to control the axis range.

- `setStartAtZero(boolean enabled)`: If this is enabled, this axis will always have it's minimum value at zero (0), no matter which kind of data the chart displays.
- `setAxisMaxValue(float max)`: Set a custom maximum value for this axis. If set, this value will not be calculated automatically depending on the provided data.
- `setAxisMinValue(float min)`: Set a custom minimum value for this axis. If set, this value will not be calculated automatically depending on the provided data.
- `setSpaceTop(float percent)`: Sets the top spacing (in percent of the total axis-range) of the highest value in the chart in comparison to the highest value on the axis.
- `setSpaceBottom(float percent)`: Sets the bottom spacing (in percent of the total axis-range) of the lowest value in the chart in comparison to the lowest value on the axis.

Comment: Thx, I will try these methods

Comment: But Why this happen, I still confuse ? The max and min value will be calculated automatically. The stock price always stable .it should not be like the first pic.  I use the example code, it works perfect .But why my data does not work? Thank you so much.

Comment: I print the max and min value. System.out.println(chart.getYMax());
 System.out.println(chart.getYMin()); It is the value I want .but the chart still like one line? why ? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Philipp Jahoda in my barchart I have set barchart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum to zero if barchart.getYMin() >= 0,After doing so i need to update the chart data and then if barchart.getYMin() < 0 then how can i reset the axis minimum so that i can show negative value in chart??

Answer (score 15):

There is a kind of dependency between left and right axises. I had only right axis enabled and set

```
chart.getAxisRight().setStartAtZero(false);
```

but that didn't work till I set the same parameter to my leftYAxis, which was disabled. So I have now

```
 chart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(false);
 chart.getAxisRight().setStartAtZero(false);
```

edit:

setStartAtZero is deprecated, the code recommends using setAxisMinimum instead.

```
 * This method is deprecated.
 * Use setAxisMinimum(...) / setAxisMaximum(...) instead.
```

You can find more on that in the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis).

Comment: That's what i wanted, Thanks a lot. You saved my time

Comment: `chart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(false);` worked for me ... thanks,But now what happens is minValue is 98 it is setting 98 as starting, I want it to be stareted from 95, if minValue is 106 it should be 105 or 100; if minValue is 0.25 then 0.20 & 3.49 then 3.45 ... likewise ... Means starting value should be lesser a bit then the minValue...

Comment: and also on pinch zoom it looks weird as the values are nearby ex: 0.2349,0.2351,0.2334,0.2354,0.2156,0.3002,0.4545,0.1895,0.19010,0.2995,0.2901... so it will display the Yaxis as  0.18, 0.19, 0.21, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.25, 0.29, 0.29, 0.30,  ... How to handle this? with your provided solution

Comment: This does not work for me at all on version 2.1.6. What versions are you on?

Comment: @Mark_1955 the project is on an old version (my gradle doesn't say anything about it). I cloned it about a year ago and since then hasn't pull changes.

Comment: Deprecated methods

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the

```
mChart.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(150, AxisDependency.LEFT);
```

method to set highest visible value on y axis.

Answer (score 1):

use setScaleMinima()
and chart.moveViewToY(max), YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

please try this , i am not sure that what your want.when i face minim zoom level in MPAndroidChart i used this method like this,

**mChart.setPinchZoom(true);
mChart.setScaleMinima(200,200);** //for min and max value for zoom
i
Hope to be ok for your problem

Comment: So if use setScaleMinima() . how to make the chart in the center of the view

Comment: @Urchin i used like in my xml file to make in the center of the view
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me (I'm not sure why). However, I made it work using:

```
ratingTracker.getAxisLeft().mAxisMaximum = max;
ratingTracker.getAxisLeft().mAxisMinimum = min;
```

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Mp Android Line chart in this fix the Y-Axis Minimum and maximum value so your graph line value start middle of the graph chart.

use this function so your problem will solve

yAxis.setAxisMinimum();

yAxis.setAxisMaximum();

in this code you can put any value you want and your graph Y-axis line
Minimum and Maximum value

Try below line of code :

**YAxis yAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();**

**yAxis.setEnabled(false);**

**yAxis.setAxisMinimum(-400);**

**yAxis.setAxisMaximum(400);**